# SoftAssert not throwing all fails at a time instead its throwing only first fail when it have more than one

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assert, assertion

I have written a test and asserting it with SoftAssert, I have written multiple assert fail statements to understand the SoftAssert concept, the code executed completely and the Soft Assert thrown exception only at end, but its not throwing all fails at a time, instead its throwing only the first fail, while i am expecting list of all fails.

I have tried executing the same code by fixing each fail statement which it thrown as fail, then it would thrown the next immediately occurred fail but not all available fails,in shot , i am expecting to see list of all fails but its throwing one fail at a time

```
public class GoogleTest extends Browser {
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
@Test
public void search(){
    Logger logger 
    =org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
    logger.info("GoogleTest-Search test");

    GooglePageObjects obj=PageFactory.
    initElements(Browser.getBrowserObject(),GooglePageObjects.class);
    softAssert.assertEquals("test", "test");
    softAssert.assertEquals("Test", "TesT","Both Values DOnot Match");
    softAssert.assertNotEquals("actual", "actual", "Both values are same 
    so its a fail");
    softAssert.assertEquals(true, false, "Expected both as true but its 
    not");
    softAssert.assertSame(1, 2, "Both are not same");

    obj.searchInGoogle("apple");
    obj.searchInGoogle("banana");
    obj.searchInGoogle("blue berry");

    softAssert.assertAll();
    }
    }
```

Expected: To see list of all fail statement in the testng console
Actual: Even though my code have multiple fail assert statements, the control is throwing only first occurred fail statement instead of all

Comment: Can you post the assertion message?

Comment: For some unknown reason i was not able to see all assertion messages, but, now i am able to see it.in the error trace. java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
 Both Values DOnot Match expected [TesT] but found [Test],
 Both values are same so its a fail,
 Expected both as true but its not expected [false] but found [true],
 Both are not same expected [2] but found [1]